# Sharepoint Nintex workflow sending multiply notifications when only one is needed

Tags: sharepoint-2010, notifications, nintex-workflow

I am having problems with a Nintex workflow. When it triggers it sends multiple notifications when it should only send one. What I’m trying to achieve is an email notification which emails, the form filler when the form submission date is overdue.

**Workflow Name: PIF overdue review**

The main logic used is `[todaydate]` which is a workflow variable equalling ‘Current date’ and a list field `[Due Date]` which is filled in by user at the start of the form filling process.

*Settings for the 'todaydate' workflow variable:*
[image: todaydate workflow variable]

Once `[todaydate]` is greater than `[Due date]` (and as long as the  `[Issue Status]` = ‘Assigned’ or ‘Investigated’) ; I would like an email sent to a few managers (`[Responsible Manager]` and `[Attention of]` Manager) and a list filled called `[RAG]` (Red. Amber.Green) changed to ‘RED’.

It worked perfectly a day or two ago but now it sends the notification email x9 each time, any clues where I’m going wrong?

*My Nintex Process Map looks like this:*

[image: My Nintex process map looks like this:]

### Step 1) SET A CONDITION:

The `[Due Date field]` on the current item is greater than Variable `[todaydate]` and The `[Issue Status]` field on the current item equals 'Assigned' or The `[Issue Status]` field on the current item equals 'Investigated'.

```
YES >   **Set field Value**> `[RAG Status]` to ‘RED’ > **Send Notification**> 

NO > **End Workflow**
```

[image]

### Step 2) END WORKFLOW

[image: End Workflow]

### Step 3) SET FIELD VALUE

[image: SET FIELD VALUE]

### Step 4) SEND NOTIFICATION

[image: SEND NOTIFICATION]

### WORKFLOW SETTINGS:

[image: todaydate workflow variable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set "Start when items are modified" to "No" to get rid of multiple notifications.

See http://connect.nintex.com/files/folders/tutorials_and_how_tos_nw2010/entry12084.aspx to learn more on reminders and escalations.